# Bourne shell: split string according to multiple criteria (iptables multiport limitation)

Tags: string, shell, split, sh

I am writing a routine in Bourne shell to command iptables, which does an intensive use of the "multiport" parameter.

iptables allows maximum 15 references to the multiport parameter. These references can be individual (counting 1) or ranges (counting 2).

I would need to break a long string of ports mixed between single and ranges in a usable way for iptables multiport.

e.g. given a list of 18 references 18 individual ports and 2 ranges:

```
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30:40,60,61,62,63,64,65:70
```

I'm trying to work out a way to split the string and any similar one into sets of maximum 15 references like in this case 15+3:

```
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30:40,60,61,62,63
64,65:70
```

The trick being: ranges can't be split on different lines. So if the original input was instead :

```
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30:40,60,61,62,63:64,65:70
```

I would need to split (14+4):

```
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30:40,60,61,62
63:64,65:70
```

Is there any smart way to achieve this, perhaps using awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple Awk script to collect as many items of the same kind as possible on the same line.

```
awk -v RS=',' -F : '{ gsub(/\n$/, "") }
    NF > 1 { r=(r ? r "," : "") $0;                                                                              
        if (r ~ /([^,]*,){6}/) { print r; r=""; } next }                        
    { s=(s ? s "," : "") $0;                                                    
        if (s ~ /([^,]*,){14}/) { print s; s=""; } }                            
    END { if (r && s) {                                                         
            p = r "," s; if (p !~ /([^,:]*[:,]){15}/) { print p; r=s="" } }     
        if (r) print r ; if (s) print s }'
```

The changed `RS` (record separator) means commas are split as if they were newlines, and within those records ("lines"), a colon is seen as a field separator.  Then we just check whether there are more than two fields in the input, and collect up to 8 pairs or 15 singletons before printing a batch.

With the input

```
21:22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30:40,60,61,62,63,64,65:70
```

it prints

```
21:22,30:40,65:70
23,24,25,26,27,28,29,60,61,62,63,64
```

You can play with it here: http://ideone.com/a3PCzs

Comment: This looks smart! Haven't tested it yet, but how would it behave if I have a line with 8 ranges (16 references)? Also (not part of the OP) there's no need to split individual ports from ranges, i was quite happy to keep them in the same order provided by the port list.

Comment: The input `21:22,23:24,25:26,27:28,29,30:40,60:61,62:63,64:65,70` gets split into `21:22,23:24,25:26,27:28,30:40,60:61,62:63,64:65` and `29,70`.

Comment: If you have a long list of ports this doesn't work. Try e.g. against:

1:2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10:11,12:13,14:15,21,25,44,53,80,123,443,465,993,1194:1197,1723,3658,4000,4200:4380,5730:5739,6665:6670,8080,8800:8899,14020,27000:27050

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to avoid empty lines without complicating the script too much. Updated to just accept that there will be some empty lines.

Comment: Much better but still one problem. If you feed the sting:
1:2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10:11,12:13,14:15,21,25,44,53,80,123,443,465,993,1194:1197,172‌3,3658,4000,4200:4380,5730:5739,6665:6670,8080,8800:8899,14020,27000:27050

(empty line not a problem btw!)

The second line in output will have 20 elements. As per original question a range counts 2 against the 15 limitation

Comment: Oh, that's easy to fix.  Updated answer.

Comment: I got to the answer myself after I posted and changed the 14 for a 7.
I have to say "it works" because it does! But I was wondering if there's a way to have a better approach though as with the example given in the comment I get 4 strings of 15,14,6,6 elements. having 15,15 11 would be perfect but even  15,14,12 still acceptable (looking to reduce the number of output line wherever possible)

Comment: Updated once more to collect all the residue on one final line if possible.

Comment: WOW! This latest version does it! :-) One final comment if I might (already happy with the script as it is though!). for extremely long input strings (e.g. more than 3 lines output), the optimization fades away a little.

1:2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9:10,11:14,15,16,17:19,21,25,27:29,30:35,36,37,38:41,44,53,67,80,123,443,465,993,1194:1197,1723,3658,4000:4200,4380,5730:5739,6665:6670,8080,8800:8899,14020,27000:27050

Comment: Not sure I understand your latest comment; could you explain what the problem is?

Comment: Oh no, no problems at all! I'm just saying, if I run the very last long list of ports again the script you get 14,15,12,10.... rather than have all the line 14 or 15 and only the very last one less than that. Again not an issue.